# Is there a way to "preselect" a certain user on the Windows 7 login screen?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, login-screen

On one of my computers with Windows 7 I have a fairly long list of users, while I'm the only one using it locally with some regularity.
Is there any way to have a certain (or simply the last) user automatically be selected so I don't have to tab/mouse through the list every time the computer starts up?

Comment: Without using an auto-login, which defeats the purpose of your password?  Probably not.

Comment: Its all about security, if MS made that possible malware would have a party on your PC.

Comment: @Moab: How does automatically picking a user account make it less secure?

Comment: Anything that removes user interaction to log on is less secure.

Comment: @Moab: No, since 1) all user accounts are publicly listed, it's just a matter of convenience and 2) the poster does *not* ask for the *password* to be entered automatically.

Comment: This is not about bypassing the password, but about having a certain user selected in the list. On a home computer, I don't see the security issue. @Moab

Comment: @Iszi: I have previously _had_ an autologin, followed by an immediate autolock (supposedly the Vista/7 startup items cannot be bypassed; can't confirm that), but the security implications of that are what prompted me to ask this question.

Comment: @oKtosiTe, it definitely can be bypassed. Try starting up in safe mode, or just pressing and holding the `Shift` key as you log in, and that will be bypassed.

Comment: @nhinkle: Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered previously on [social.technet.microsoft.com](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/777b2086-19fb-4c75-9b8d-a88c07607f4e) and unfortunately, the answer seems to be **No**.

> Logon screen shows the user accounts
>   in alphabetical order based on the
>   names first given to the account when
>   it is created. If you change the user
>   account name later, it does no longer
>   change the order accounts are
>   presented. Reason is simple: even if
>   you change the user account name
>   later, the user account folder keeps
>   the original name. Renaming the user
>   subfolders in C:\Users does not change
>   the situation.
>
> What all this means is that you have
>   to think the logon screen account
>   order already when creating accounts.

Comment: Although the answer probably _is_ no, the order is of no interest to me. On older versions of Windows (2000 springs to mind) it was at least possible to show the last used user name, shortening the login process slightly. If there would be a way to simply type my user name instead of having to select it from a list, that would already be a great step forward.

Comment: @oKtosiTe: You mean you *can't* do that? // The "classic" login screen is still present and can be re-enabled. In Windows XP you could also invoke it by pressing Ctrl-Alt-Del twice while in the Welcome screen; I heard this has been removed in Vista in favor of *making the username itself editable*.

Answer (score 0):

What works fairly well for me now, is to have Windows "not display [the] last user name".
This way I'm simply asked to enter my username manually, which —considering my four letter name— requires far fewer keypresses than navigating the list.

To change this setting (on Windows 7):

- Run `%WinDir%\System32\gpedit.msc`
- Navigate to `Computer Configuration` > `Windows Settings` > `Security Settings` > `Local Policies` > `Security Options`
- Enable "`Interactive logon: Do not display last user name`"

Answer (score -1):

Using the Fast User Switching changes the order. The last logged is user will be the first. "Set" the order with it, then: disable the Lock Screen then disable Fast User Switching.

It is works on Win 10. (i have tested it)

(delete my answear if is doesn't help, but this worked for me)