# How to set user account as default selected in login screen on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, login, user-accounts, login-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to “preselect” a certain user on the Windows 7 login screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/251399/is-there-a-way-to-preselect-a-certain-user-on-the-windows-7-login-screen)

How can I set a user account to be selected per default in login screen on windows 7 so that I don't have to click on the account on every boot. I just want to type the password and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

You could automate the login with some Windows Registry settings, but if entering your password is a requirement then this isn't going to be the right solution for you.

How to turn on automatic logon in Windows XP
  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315231